# Returning byte array from C# DLL to C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am returning a byte array `byte[] result` from a function in C# DLL as:

```
void WriteSingleCoils(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startAddress, bool OnOff, ref byte[] result)
```

I am calling this function from the C++ code. All other parameters have no problem but how to pass the last parameter `result` which is actually a returning argument from the C++ code?

Comment: And what's the problem? Is the code not working properly? Show your code please.

Comment: An array is already a reference type.  You probably should not be stacking the `ref` keyword on top of that.  If your function is in fact creating a new array rather than filling in one provided by the caller, you can't use it with C++ at all (C++ doesn't know how to manage memory owned by the C# garbage collector, which a newly created array would be)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

```
void WriteSingleCoils(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startAddress, bool OnOff, array<Byte> ^result)
```

It is tested. Works fine for me.